# owin Authentication With Xing

Tags: authentication, owin, xing

my plan is to use Xing as Social Login. My Problem is I can't find god Samples for Custom Authentication for OWIN.

For Google+ its Simple

```
//IAppBuilder app
    app.UseGoogleAuthentication(new GoogleOAuth2AuthenticationOptions()
            {
              ClientId = "xyz",
              ClientSecret = "abc"
            });
```

I had create a Xing App and got the Id and Secret from this App. But how do i create a Custom Authentication with this id and Secret ? And how do i  use it ?

Comment: You need to wait MS support this :).

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
var xingOptions = new XingAuthenticationOptions()
{
    ConsumerKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xingConsumerKey"],
    ConsumerSecret = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["xingConsumerSecret"]
};

app.UseXingAuthentication(xingOptions);
```